# Change of element in column not updating in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, rename

I am trying to update the names in a pandas dataframe column. I want:

[IN]

```
B17.31
107.34
34
B50.56
```

[OUT]

```
B17.31
B107.34
B34
B50.56
```

The code I am using is:

```
for file in df1.loc[:, '#filename']:
    new = str(file)
    if new[0] != 'B':
       final = new[:0] + 'B' + new[0:]
    else:
        final = new

    print((final))
    df1.replace(new, final)

print(df1['#filename'])
df1.to_csv('updated_name_data.csv')
```

I can not work out why it will print out the updated name but will not update in the dataframe or csv. Any help or a pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
for file in df1.loc[:, '#filename']:
    new = str(file)
    if new[0] != 'B':
       final = new[:0] + 'B' + new[0:]
    else:
        final = new

    print((final))
    df1.replace(new, final,inplace=True)# yuo are not using inplace=True, this is required as otherwise this will return the old dataframe after replacement

    print(df1['#filename'])
    df1.to_csv('updated_name_data.csv')
```

Comment: @p.strain you are welcome, do accept my answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: @p.strain - Hmmm, there is some reason for use loops? It is no problem it is slow? Or small data, so no problem? I am a bit curious...

Comment: I am using the loop as its for a data set with 10,000 names. Relatively new to python so if there is a faster way would definitely give it a go.

Comment: @p.strain there are definitely faster ways. for loop is quite time consuming

Answer (score 0):

In pandas is best avoid loops, because slow, better is use vectorized functions.

So you can create boolean mask by [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and then add `B` to original column with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = df1['#filename'].astype(str).str.startswith('B')
df1['#filename'] = np.where(mask, df1['#filename'], 'B' + df1['#filename'].astype(str))
```

Another similar solution with inverting mask by `~`:

```
df1.loc[~mask, '#filename'] =  'B' + df1['#filename'].astype(str)
```

---

```
print (df1)
 #filename
0    B17.31
1   B107.34
2       B34
3    B50.56
```

Answer (score 0):

You should aim to use vectorised operations rather than a manual loop. For example, you can isolate numeric values and prefix with `"B"`:

```
s = pd.Series(['B17.31', 107.34, 34, 'B50.56'])

mask = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').notnull()
s.loc[mask] = 'B' + s.astype(str)

print(s)

0     B17.31
1    B107.34
2        B34
3     B50.56
dtype: object
```